# share files using ACTION_SEND not working for share IT android

Tags: android, android-intent

share files using ACTION_SEND not working for share IT android

I am trying to share an Image using

```
String path = newString;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

however I get the error `sending this content type is not supported`

Is there a tool or utility which can make sharing easy

**what I am looking for is an alternative to Intent.ACTION_SEND**

to send files on youtube, FB, share it, mail  or  other social media or other platform

I don't want to use wifi direct as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
try {

                    String path = newString;
                    File myFile = new File(path);
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                    sharingIntent.setType(getMimeType(myFile.getPath()));
                    sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",Uri.fromFile(myFile));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }



public String getMimeType(String filePath) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePath);
        if (extension != null) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public String getFileExtensionFromUrl(String url) {
        int dotPos = url.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (0 <= dotPos) {
            return (url.substring(dotPos + 1)).toLowerCase();
        }
        return "";
    }
```